# Remote Wipe out an iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have developed an iPad application and I have distributed that application to my clients. Now my clients ask what will happen if their iPad lost or stolen. My iPad application has very sensitive data. So they need to wipe out remotely if iPad is stolen or lost. 
I found two solutions. 
One is configure 'Find My iPad' in each iPad with same apple account.
Second one is configuring MDM server with push notifications.

If I'm going to configure MDM server I need to contact third party vendor who supports push notifications service of apple or I need to buy Lion Server and configure profile Manager.

Can some one tell me what is the best solution to implement and pros and cons of these two options.

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications won't help you here - they only will pop up a message to the user, you cannot influence the app from them.

Possible solutions:

- **Protect your app with username / password**: Each user should choose a username and password, store those in the keychain and check on app start. Of course you should also encrypt all data with the password when storing it to the device.
- Like said above, implement a **server request which gets the unique id** of the installed app (of course you'd have to create one first on first app startup), **returns whether the app is reported as stolen** and then either do nothing or delete all data. I'd be careful about deleting though in case there was an error somewhere in your implementation and you wipe out a 'normal' application's data. Also in this case I'd encrypt any sensitive data that is stored to the device. This solution also won't work when the app is offline, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a web service and get response from server, and after getting response , run your application otherwise kill.

```
if(stolen)
exit(0);
else
run
```